# node.js + sequelize + query execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

In my node app i am using sequelize ORM. In that i have to execute 3 queries and after all are exxecuted i have to combine those results into JSON format.

My queries:

```
try {
    sequelize.query("select id_0, name_0, id_1, name_1 from xxxx group by id_0, name_0, id_1, name_1").success(function (result) {
        finalResult = result;

    })
} catch (err) {

}

try {
    sequelize.query("select yyyyyyyyyy(JSON datatype) as value from xxxxx limit 1").success(function (valueResults) {
        valueResults = valueResults[0].value;
        valueResults = JSON.parse(valueResults);
        for (var prop in valueResults) {
            keyResult.push(prop);
        }
    })
} catch (err) {

}

try {
    sequelize.query("select country_name, level0, level1, level2, level3, level4 from levels").success(function (result) {
        //console.log("ccccccc=" +util.inspect(levelsResult)); = result;
        levelsResult = result;

    })
} catch (err) {

}
```

I have to combine the 3 outputs into single and i have to format into JSON. when i tried to print these 3 outputs at last its coming as empty because of async calls.Please help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't continually edit your question.  If you want to bring more attention to it, add a bounty.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a flow control package to help with this. There are pure JS ways of doing so, but a package like [async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) or some promise implementation would work just as well (unless you want the exercise).

An example in `async` would be the `async.series` or `async.parallel` method (unsure your call sequence if they need to be sequential or parallel). Like this:

```
var async = require('async');

async.parallel({
  query1 : function( cb ){
    //perform query here. Put cb() inside callback, where you get results
    cb(null, "result1");
  },
  query2 : function( cb ){
    //perform query here. Put cb() inside callback, where you get results
    cb(null, "result2");
  },
  query3 : function( cb ){
    //perform query here. Put cb() inside callback, where you get results
    cb(null, "result3");
  }
},function parallelFinal(parallelErr, parallelResults){
  if( parallelErr ) throw new Error("Something bad!");
  console.log("Results are " + JSON.stringify( parallelResults ) );
});
```

Results in:

> Results are {"query1":"result1","query2":"result2","query3":"result3"}

You can set and manipulate the objects in the resulting method as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Either go with the solution @clay told you or do the queries inside the query callback, that is to say:

```
var result1, result2, result3
try {
    sequelize.query("select foo from bar").success(function (foo) {
    result1 = foo;
    try {
        sequelize.query("select foo2 from bar2").success(function (bar) {
            result2 = bar;
            //do the 3rd query here
        });
    } catch (e) {

    }
})
} catch (err) {

}
```

Bear in mind that this approach is not practical when you want to do several queries, this approach is a simple blocking code, that is the opposite to how node.js works (non-blocking)